# Why can't I use a lambda expression when calling Constructor.newInstance()?

Tags: java, lambda, reflection

I am trying to instantiate an object using `Constructor.newInstance`. The constructor requires one argument of type `DoubleSupplier`. This is successful if I first create a `DoubleSupplier` object, then pass the object to the `newInstance` method:

```
DoubleSupplier  supplier    = () -> 3.0;
obj = ctor.newInstance( supplier );
```

But if I try using the lambda directly in the `newInstance` invocation:

```
obj = ctor.newInstance( () -> 3.0 );
```

it fails to compile with "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface." What is the difference between the two methods?

Incidentally, I can use the lambda when instantiating an object using `new`.

```
obj2 = new SubTypeA( () -> 3.0 );
```

Sample program follows.

```
public class CtorDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SuperType   obj = getSubType( SubTypeA.class );
        System.out.println( obj.getClass().getName() );
    }
    
    private static SuperType 
    getSubType( Class<? extends SuperType> clazz )
    {
        SuperType   obj = null;
        try
        {
            Constructor<? extends SuperType> ctor    =
                clazz.getConstructor( DoubleSupplier.class );
            
            DoubleSupplier  supplier    = () -> 3.0;
            obj = ctor.newInstance( supplier );
            // obj = ctor.newInstance( () -> 3.0 );
            // compile error
        }
        catch ( NoSuchMethodException
                | InvocationTargetException 
                | IllegalAccessException 
                | InstantiationException exc )
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            System.exit( 1 );
        }
        return obj;
    }

    private static class SuperType
    {
    }
    private static class SubTypeA extends SuperType
    {
        public SubTypeA( DoubleSupplier supplier )
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Reflection at all Something like `(SubTypeA::new).apply(() -> 3.0);`. Probably two typecasts required in there.

Comment: As the above comment says, don’t use Reflection. Use something like `Function<DoubleSupplier, SuperType> f = SubTypeA::new; SuperType obj = f.apply(() -> 3.0);`

Comment: BTW it is same reason why `Object supplier = () -> 3.0;` will not work; Java Language Specification [15.27.3. Type of a Lambda Expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3): "A lambda expression is compatible in an assignment context, invocation context, or casting context with a target type `T` if `T` is a functional interface type and ..." - `Object` is not a functional type.

Answer (score 5):

`newInstance` is reflection based. The input parameters here are of the class `Object`, which can't handle lambdas without casting, like this:

```
obj = ctor.newInstance((DoubleSupplier) () -> 3.0 );
```

Comment: `newInstance` is not “reflection based”, it is part of Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer from @sam, the type of a lambda expression is determined in context, by the compiler. Given:

```
public static void methodA( DoubleSupplier supplier )
{
}
public static void methodB( Object obj )
{
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    methodA( () -> 3. );
    methodB( (DoubleSupplier)() -> 3. );
    // methodB( () -> 3. );
    // compile error
}
```

In the invocation of methodA the compiler determines the type of the lambda expression from the type of methodA's parameter. In the first invocation of methodB the cast is telling the compiler how to determine the type of the lambda expression. In the case of the second invocation of methodB, we get a compiler error, because there's not enough context for the compiler to figure out what to do with the lambda exression.

The problem is not directly related to reflection.